# No se inserta a la base de datos

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

No entiendo porque no se esta realizando ni la verificación ni el insert a la base de datos, si me pudieran guiar para saber cual es mi error

conexion.php

```
<?php
$connect;
function connect(){
    $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","pagina");

    if (!$connect) {
        die('Contacte al administrador de la página ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else{
    
        return $connect;
    }
  }
?>
```

insertar.php

```
<?php
require_once "conexion.php";
$mysqli = connect();

  function insertar(){
        if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
          $nombre = $_POST['firstName'];
          $apellido = $_POST['secondName'];
          $correo = $_POST['email'];
          $pass = $_POST['pass'];
          $id = rand(1,99);

         $query = "INSERT INTO signup (idSign, firstName, secondName, email, pass) 
         VALUES ($id, $nombre, $apellido, $correo, $pass)";

         if(mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)){
          header("Location: index.php");
          echo "Welcome!";
            } else{
              echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $query. " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
            }
        }
    }
    function consultar(){
        validar($_POST['email'],$_POST['password']);

    function validar($correo,$password){
        $mysqli = connect();
        $password = ($pass);
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE email = '".$correo."' && pass = '".$pass."';";
        $resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);
        
        if ($resultado->num_rows === 0) { //validación === 0
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'The User or password is wrong';           
            $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'danger'; 
            header("Location: index.php");         
        }
        else{
            while ($datos = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
                assign($datos[0],$datos[3]);
            }
            $_SESSION['started'] = 1;
            header('Location: index.php');
            echo'Welcome back '.$datos[3].'';
            echo'Welcome back name '.$_SESSION["name"].''; 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

signup.php y login.php

```
<?php
require_once "conexion.php";
require_once "insertar.php";
?>
<button type="submit" onclick="insertar();" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4">
    Sign up
 </button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg px-5" type="submit" onclick="validar();">Login</button>
```

en los botones estos se encuentran en el signup.php y en login.php pero estos tienen un formato parecido, con el php que manda a llamar a la conexión y donde se encuentran las funciones que se realizan.
en los botones tengo la duda si son onclick o action para realizar las funciones de los php, tambien puede que sea otro mi error pero no estoy seguro

Comment: ¿Dónde se supone que llamas a tus funciones PHP?

Comment: segun yo en el php arriba hago el requiere_once y en los botones hago el onclick mandando a llamar la funcion, pero no estoy seguro si debe de ser onclick o action

Comment: No, no funciona así. Tu botón está **de otro lado** (en el cliente) y el código PHP está en el servidor. Es fundamental comprender que cada cosa está de un lado distinto... Para comunicar entre ambos lados, hay varias formas: 1. Mandando un formulario; 2. Mandando una URL; 3. Pasando los datos por Ajax o por Fetch. La mejor forma de todas es la tercera, porque puedes pasar datos de un lado a otro sin recargar la página. En los casos 1 y 2 tendrás que recargar la página. Te recomiendo que leas sobre Ajax y que trates de implementar esa forma.

Comment: Por otro lado, tienes un error de _corta y pega_ de código antiguo en esta línea: `die('Contacte al administrador de la página ' . mysql_error());`  pues debes cambiar el  `mysql_error()` por `mysqli_error($connect)` (las funciones `mysql_*` estan obsoletas desde hace muchas versiones atras de PHP).  Y en ese mismo archivo no se que pinta la primera línea donde pones `$connect;` y te quedas tan ancho, como si eso hiciera alguna cosa, que no la hace.